# CSS: 2nd iframe won't render

Tags: html, css, iframe

Only the Iframe1 is rendered. The Iframe2 is hidden. I wanted Iframe2 to start at the lower border of Iframe1 and fill the rest of the page. (live example: http://flippa.com/auctions/2627927/site)

```
<style type="text/css">
        #Iframe1
        {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height:100px;
            margin:0px; 
            z-index:2;
        }

        #Iframe2
        {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%; 
            margin:0px; 
            top:100px;
            z-index:3;
        }
</style>


<body>
    <iframe  src="http://www.google.com" id="Iframe1"
     scrolling="no"  frameborder="0"><iframe/> 

    <iframe  src="http://www.yahoo.com" id="Iframe2"
     scrolling="no" frameborder="0"> </iframe> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem that your first `iframe` has a closing tag like this:

`<iframe/>`

instead of like this:

`</iframe>`

Answer (score 2):

your first iframe has an invalid closing tag:

```
<iframe/>
```

change to

```
</iframe>
```